# Add existing list column to view without altering whatever the columns may be for the existing view

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell

Is there a way to add existing columns to the view. Set-PnPView will create a new view determined by the fields specified -- I just want to add existing columns to what's already in the view for hundreds of libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a test using pnp powershell to update the list view in a list, you need to make some changes to meet your requirements.

```
#Config Variables
$SiteURL = "https://crescenttech.sharepoint.com"
$ListName= "Projects"
$ViewName= "Active Projects"
$ColumnName = "Category" #Internal Name
 
#Get Credentials to connect
$Cred = Get-Credential
 
Try {
    #Connect to PNP Online
    Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -Credentials $Cred
 
    #Get the Context
    $Context = Get-PnPContext
 
    #Get the List View from the list
    $ListView  =  Get-PnPView -List $ListName -Identity $ViewName -ErrorAction Stop
 
    #Check if view doesn't have the column already
    If($ListView.ViewFields -notcontains $ColumnName)
    {
        #Add Column to View
        $ListView.ViewFields.Add($ColumnName)
        $ListView.Update()
        $Context.ExecuteQuery()
        Write-host -f Green "Column '$ColumnName' Added to View '$ViewName'!"
    }
    else
    {
        Write-host -f Yellow "Column '$ColumnName' Already Exists in View '$ViewName'!"
    }
}
catch {
    write-host "Error: $($_.Exception.Message)" -foregroundcolor Red
}
```

More information:

https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2016/05/sharepoint-online-add-remove-fields-to-list-view-using-powershell.html